# Predicting Sales With and Without Events?

Tags: machine-learning, variance

I have data from a retailer that contains aggregate sales over weekly periods, grouped by postal codes.

Within this data, there are several 'promotional events' that occur at various discrete time periods, typically lasting a week.

My goal is to determine, for each postal code, the impact of these events on sales. The analyst I'm working with wants to know the overall sales 'lift' for each event by *simulating sales without an event* and comparing it to the actual event sales. How is this even possible?

I've never done anything like this before. I've built a model that can predict sales on this dataset but it doesn't consider the sales impact of events or lack thereof.

I'm looking for some advice as to how to accurately quantify the impact of these events on sales data. Any insight into an effective approach to this would be greatly appreciated.

Could this be considered time-series data? I don't think it is, since there are multiple time entries for each individual postal code.

As an example, some of my data looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
| postal_code | week_start |  week_end  | event_week | sales  |     event      |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-11-15 | 2018-11-21 |     201929 | 139.21 | No Event       |
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-11-22 | 2018-11-28 |     201930 | 146.37 | No Event       |
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-11-29 | 2018-12-05 |     201931 |    258 | No Event       |
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-12-06 | 2018-12-12 |     201932 |  94.21 | No Event       |
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-12-13 | 2018-12-19 |     201933 |  59.44 | No Event       |
| B3H1Z8      | 2018-12-20 | 2018-12-26 |     201934 | 195.82 | No Event       |
| K1C2C5      | 2019-04-25 | 2019-05-01 |     201952 |  18.98 | WK51 WE Apr 24 |
| K1C2C5      | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-08 |     202001 |  87.06 | No Event       |
| K1C2C5      | 2019-05-09 | 2019-05-15 |     202002 | 100.42 | No Event       |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-11-08 | 2018-11-14 |     201928 | 131.77 | WK27 WE Nov 07 |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-11-15 | 2018-11-21 |     201929 |   7.46 | WK28 WE Nov 14 |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-11-22 | 2018-11-28 |     201930 |  58.82 | WK29 WE Nov 21 |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-11-29 | 2018-12-05 |     201931 |  41.32 | WK30 WE Nov 28 |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-12-06 | 2018-12-12 |     201932 |  43.77 | WK31 WE Dec 05 |
| K1C2J3      | 2018-12-13 | 2018-12-19 |     201933 | 139.32 | WK32 WE Dec 12 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you have is called panel data. And finding the "effect" of the promotional event on sales is called causal inference. The main challenge of this problem is to find out the effect unadulterated by confounding factors likes seasonality of sales, regional variations, aggregate disposable income fluctations, similar events by competitors.

The best case to solve this problem is to have a natural experiment where some customers are randomly assigned to the event (they hear about the event and can avail the promotion) and some aren't. Assuming the random assigned is truly random, we can calculate the difference in sales to the two groups, and, we have the effect of sales.

Unfortunately, we don't have such an experiment. Your analyst is trying to "create" a random assignment by simulating non-event sales. It may or may not work.

The easiest method you have at your disposal is to regress sales on a dummy for promotional events with fixed effects for the time of the month, postal code/state, economic conditions (state gdp/national gdp etc.), events by competitors etc..

There are other methods like instrumental variables, difference-in-differences, and regression discontinuity design. They require careful thinking to get right. Among these, I think difference-in-differences could be a good method for you: that is, compare a postal code which had the promotional event with nearby postal code which didn't have the event.